# Expressão regular, PHP

Tags: php, regex

Qual a forma correta de validar a string para a nomenclatura abaixo, usando Expressão regular?

`/filmes/todos-filmes/notas-espectadores/?page=[SÓ NUMEROS]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente isso:

```regex
/filmes/todos-filmes/notas-espectadores/\?page=\d+
```

A barra invertida antes do `?` é pelo fato do `?` sozinho ser um caractere especial.

O `\d` significa "digito", e o `+` em seguida significa "um ou mais", ou seja, tem que ter um ou mais dígitos para ser válido.

### Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
$padrao='~/filmes/todos-filmes/notas-espectadores/\?page=\d+~';

if preg_match($padrao, $endereco) {
   ...
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7wMIuv)**.

Ao usar no código a seguir, colocamos `~` nas "pontas" da *string*. Eles não fazem parte da expressão, eles são os delimitadores, que separam o conteudo das *flags* quando houver. É muito comum o uso de `/` como delimitador, mas como o texto já tem barras, o `~` fica diferente o suficiente para não confundir. A sintaxe é:

```
    delimitador expressão delimitador flags
```

Exemplo:

```
    /\d+/i
```

Neste caso a expressão é apenas `\d+` e a *flag* é `i`. As `/` são só para separar. O primeiro caractere usado é para indicar qual é o delimitador, e a ocorrência seguinte dele indica fim da expressão.

Comment: esses `~` é por influencia de alguém? :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert atualizei a resposta com mais detalhes. Você é adepto dos `~` né. De repente anda influenciando a galera, vai saber :)

Comment: Pois é, sempre respondo usando ele. E recomendo.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Acho mais legível em muitas situaçoes, concordo com a preferência. Quando é coisa muito simples eu acho que a barra vai bem, tipo `/Você tem (\d+) mensagens/` mas começou a encher de símbolo, o `~` me parece muito mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que o comportamento esperado para um parâmetro invalido é 404. Recomendo esquecer expressão regular e fazer dessa forma:

```
  $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
  if ($page==0) {
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  }
```

Comment: Concordo, foi uma sugestão de uma solução alternativa, já que o parâmetro "page" da a entender que ele quer verificar se a nº da página fornecida é valido.

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente neste caso seria:

```
preg_match('/(?:page[\=]([0-9]+))/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $resultado);


if((isset($resultado[1]) == true) and ($resultado[1] != null)){

echo "Pagina existe! Vamos para lá?!";

} else {

echo "Essa página não existe cara! Elas só vão até 2!";

}
```

Seria pegado só os números no caso, mas é obrigatório que antes do número venha a ter "page=".
No meu site eu não uso Wordpress ou qualquer tipo de CMS, nem mesmo faço uso de MVC tudo no site funciona a base de 'expressões regulares'. Tem uma classe que fica de olho em tudo que é digitado na URL ou clicado e elabora todas as variáveis e se comunica com outras classes as quais de posse de tais variáveis, algumas globais devido ao seu escopo, determinam como montar a página.
Eu acho expressões regulares "fantástico". Salve quem inventou isso.